# [ElectronJS][VueJs] ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I am trying to create an VueJs and Electron app.
I am following this tutorial : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnRCX074VfA`

However, I still have this bug and I don't really know what it means...
Here is the error :

```
{ 
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported', 
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

---

Here are the version of what I am using:

- NodeJs : 20.5.0
- Electron 13.6.9
- VueJs : @vue/cli 5.0.8

I tried to change the NODE_OPTION but it didn't work : `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn electron:serve`.

Here is the error resulting : electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS.

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

PS : If you have any idea of how to create a crud by the same way in electron and VueJs I would be happy to know it.

Comment: you can get electron version with `yarn electron -v`

Comment: Thank's, I modified my code !
Then, do I have to update my electron version ?

Answer (score 0):

Node version 20 is new, while electron 13 is quite old (it uses nodejs v14.17.0 internally).

So I would upgrade electron. I personally like to do this version by version while reading the changelog for breaking changes, but in your case (small project) I would just install the newest electron version (which is 25 as of today) and see what happens.

If an api is not working then consult the api documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app

Comment: Once I try to update electron with the command `yarn add electron@latest` 

This error appears : 
`error @achrinza/node-ipc@9.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "8 || 10 || 12 || 14 || 16 || 17". Got "20.5.0"`


How can I fix it ?

Comment: I tried to update from the 13th version to the 17th and each time I tried the same error appeared...

Comment: downgrade nodejs, I recommend using a nodejs version manager, these 2 I tried: nvm, fnm but nodenv also looks promising

Comment: When you say "downgrade NodeJs" it's until how many ? like the 12 ?

Comment: depends on the electron version you wanna use, for the newest electron version it it currently 18: https://releases.electronjs.org/release/v25.4.0

Comment: Then if I use electron@25.4.0 I should use nodeJS 18 right ? And now that I have both version correct, I should download again all the dependencies of my app ?

Comment: I tried the thing you said, but I still have the same error...

Comment: what "same" error? the peer dependency error or the openssl error?

Comment: Well, the first error is the incompatibility of the versions, but I can still launch my app, and there comes the second error wich is the OPENSSL error...